# jquery getting the name of a table column

Tags: jquery, sql-server, datatable, sql-server-2014

I have a 10 column DataTable that pulls data from a SQL database. 
I am trying to give an in-line edit option that when pressing a cell in the table, a pop up window opens and you are able to edit the specific value in the cell.

My problem is that I need to find the name of the column so I know what value to change in the database. I found a way to get the column number (zero based), the number of the row I am editing and of course the new value I wish to change to.

My SQL update string looks like this:

```
"UPDATE " + tableName + " SET ??? = " + "'" + newVal + "'" + " WHERE [UserName] = " + id;
```

and as you can see I have no idea what to write instead of the "???".

Hope I was clear with my explanation.

Maybe this will help: as I said, I know the number of the column that is trying to be edited using:

```
var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far to get the column name.

Comment: Your sql string looks very suspicious. Have you ever heard about sql injection? You might want to read up about it as your code looks wide open.

Comment: @dcreight, i haven't found any thing successful to get the column name.
i did find this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885667/sql-server-select-column-by-number but i don't thing that dynamic SQL is the way for me here. must be something simpler out there.

Comment: @SeanLange, heard about it, didn't try it. ill check that out. is there a  way using SQL injection?

Comment: SQL injection is a BAD thing....not a good thing. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: I've thought of a way to bypass my problem: build a little array with 0->10 in one column and the names of the columns in the other. That way i could "convert" the number of the column to the name. 
kind of stupid but i think it will work.
Any comments?

Comment: I think the concept of editing a row of data one cell at a time seems crazy. I would suggest you edit the entire row in one operation. Then you need to fix the sql injection vulnerability.

Comment: @SeanLange, You are right, but in this case a need both "editing a row of data one cell at a time" and "editing the entire row in one operation". the latter I already have. tnx