# SQL, Renaming column names in select statement without known the original name

Tags: sql, hive

I'm new to sql and have a special demand: I have many sql queries (written by others), and I know how many columns these sqls will generate. For example, here is one of the records

```
select * from some_table
```

and I known it will generate a table contain 2 columns but I don't known the column names. I want to know if there is a way that performs like this

```
select [1] as 'Column1', [2] as 'Column2' from some_table
```

where "[1] as 'Column1'" means the first column in the query result rename to 'Column1', and "[2] as 'Column2'" means the second column rename to 'Column2'.

Update:

I solved the problem using 'UNION ALL', for example

```
select 'c1' as 'Column1', 'c2' as 'Column2' limit 0
union all
select * from some_table
```

and 'limit 0' is to remove the row ['c1', 'c2'] from the first query
. It will generate table like this

```
| Column1  | Column2 |
----------------------
| xxxx     | yyyyy   |
```

Seems works well until now, I will continue verify the correctness.

The solution comes from another question, but I failed to recall the link of that question.

Comment: You should refactor these queries and select the columns explicitly. Then you always know the names of the columns.

Comment: sadly, these sqls are written by others and it's almost impossible to refactor these queries.

Comment: do you know exact column types?

Comment: No, I only have sql query strings and the number of columns it' will generate.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are already similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882837/access-columns-of-a-table-by-index-instead-of-name-in-sql-server-stored-procedur). According to the response, this is not possible in SQL.

Comment: Sounds like that I got an impossible mission