# Sql query for non-null columns

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm trying to write a query to return each column of a table and the count of non-null values, structured as

```
        | C1 | C2 | C*
Count()
```

for a single column I'm using

```
SELECT COUNT(NULLIF(E.Id,''))
  FROM Employee as E
```

I can't wrap my head around how to recursively execute Nullif on each column without having to hardcode each column name.

Comment: The above is unlikely to work for columns that aren't a string-based data type.

Comment: *"I can't wrap my head around how to recursively execute Nullif on each column without having to hardcode each column name."* If you don't want to hard code it, you would have to use dynamic SQL. Generally, I find requirements such as these to be an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: have you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882837/access-columns-of-a-table-by-index-instead-of-name-in-sql-server-stored-procedur)

Comment: Don't wrap your head because you can't, unless you want to use dynamic sql, which probably will take more time than just to copypaste or just use excel and definitely more time than to ask the question.

Comment: it takes few seconds to copy-paste and regex-replace the name of columns. why exactly do you want to avoid hard coding?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user @Thom A pointed out in the comments- you are looking for a dynamic SQL solution.
Generally you can see all column details in a database using sys.all_columns.

Similarly you can see all tables using sys.tables and all schemas using sys.schemas (where the default schema is 'dbo').

Try: `SELECT * FROM sys.all_columns; SELECT * FROM sys.tables; SELECT * FROM sys.schemas`.

The sys.tables and sys.columns both join on the same column name, object_id.  Sys.tables joins to sys.schemas on the schema_id.

The dynamic sql is usually string concatenation to a variable.  An example I created that does what you ask with conditional aggregation:

```
DECLARE @tableName varchar(100) = 'Loan_dtl'
DECLARE @schemaName varchar(100) = 'dbo'
DECLARE @sql varchar(max) = 'SELECT '

SELECT @sql = CONCAT(@sql, 'COUNT(CASE WHEN ', C.name, ' IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS [', C.name, '], ')       
  FROM sys.tables T
    INNER JOIN sys.all_columns C ON T.object_id = C.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas S ON S.schema_id = T.schema_id
 WHERE T.name = @tableName AND S.name = @schemaName

--remove last comma in STUFF and add the FROM clause
SET @sql = CONCAT(STUFF(@sql, len(@sql), 1, ''), ' FROM ', @schemaName, '.', @tableName)
EXEC (@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

It is generic regardless how many columns a table in question has, and what data types columns have.

And no dynamic SQL.

**SQL**

```
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmpTable;

-- DDL and sample data population, start
CREATE TABLE #tmpTable  (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Col_1 VARCHAR(20), Col_2 VARCHAR(20), Col_3 VARCHAR(20), Col_4 VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO #tmpTable (Col_1, Col_2, Col_3, Col_4) VALUES
(NULL, 'Nike', 'Adidas', NULL),
(NULL, 'Nike', 'Adidas', 'Asics'),
(NULL, 'Asics', NULL, 'Asics'),
(NULL, 'Nike', NULL, 'Adidas');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT c.value('local-name(.)', 'sysname') AS column_name
    FROM #tmpTable AS t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.* FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS t1(x)
    CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/*') AS t2(c)
)
(
SELECT name AS column_name, NULL AS column_counter
FROM tempdb.sys.columns
WHERE object_id = object_id('tempdb..#tmpTable')
   AND is_nullable = 1
EXCEPT
SELECT column_name, null
FROM rs
)
UNION ALL
SELECT column_name, COUNT(*) AS column_counter
FROM rs
GROUP BY column_name;
```

**Output**

| column_name | column_counter |
| --- | --- |
| Col_1 | NULL |
| Col_2 | 4 |
| Col_3 | 2 |
| Col_4 | 3 |
| ID | 4 |