# SQL Server : select columns not by name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible in SQL Server 2008 to select columns not by their names, but in the order as they appear in the table?

The reason is that i want to select the first 5 oder 6 columns of a table, no matter what's the content, because it is possible that their names or the columns self can be changed or moved.

Comment: This looks like the same question (except they want 2 columns and you want 5/6 columns): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924365/sql-to-return-first-two-columns-of-a-table

Comment: If you think the columns names will be changed or they wil be moved, then you have a serious design problem. Tables should not be changed frequently at all and column order should never under any circumstances be changed in a table. You cahnge the column order in the selct not in the table itself.

Comment: @HLGEM: I know that this is a hard problem, but the designing of the struktur and editing of data is not under my influence thus I have no grants to change anything there. I would make a completely new structur, but the bad way is the decision of my boss...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first 5 columns you can try this:

```
select column_name,ordinal_position
  from information_schema.columns
 where table_schema = ...
   and table_name = ...
   and ordinal_position <= 5
```

Hope this works now.
Solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924365/sql-to-return-first-two-columns-of-a-table).
Edit: Updated answer - old one only selected first 5 rows, not columns.

Comment: He needs columns, not rows.