# How to get a specific column by its ordinal position in table using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I know how to query a column using `select` operation when I know the column's name, like `select name from User`, but how can I get the first column or the 2nd column or any specific column in table by **using their ordinal position**?

Comment: select  `here what columns you want separated by comma`  from table

Comment: Maybe you can find your answer here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924365/sql-to-return-first-two-columns-of-a-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924365/sql-to-return-first-two-columns-of-a-table)

Comment: you can find it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054984/how-can-i-get-column-names-from-a-table-in-sql-server

Comment: [Select column by ordinal position](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8c9a250b-05b3-49b8-b6f1-800230762688/select-column-by-ordinal-position?forum=transactsql) .