# SQL Server - select columns from given range

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table where I have columns like below

```
[Index], [Length],[N1],[N2]....[N99]
```

Now, is possible to select only `[N2]] ... [N29]` columns without writing all names.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368505/is-it-possible-to-select-sql-server-data-using-column-ordinal-position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(MAX), 
        @tablename VARCHAR(255), 
        @from VARCHAR(255), 
        @select VARCHAR(100)

SET @tablename = 'orderheader'

SELECT @columns = STUFF(
(
    SELECT ',[' + column_name + ']'
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_name = @tablename
    AND NOT column_name IN ('N2', 'Index', 'Length')
    FOR XML PATH('')
),1, 1, '')

SELECT @select = 'SELECT ', @from = ' from ' + @tablename

EXEC(@select + @columns + @from)
```

Comment: Using dynamic sql to save a couple of minutes of typing is a bad choice.

Comment: @HLGEM - That is hardly the issue here, question was can it be done. Answer is: Only with with dynamic sql, and this is how it could be done. In extreme cases it will speed up the sql alot to choose fewer columns. +1

Comment: It is the only solution.  I think that it's a bad reason to -1 me.

Comment: I don't disagree with HLGEM, although, the dynamic SQL solution would handle if a new column was added.  Since they have column names such as N2...N100, I suggest that they insert columns frequently.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. You need to explicitly list the subset of columns you want to return.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible without writing all names.

Answer (score 1):

You can of course drag and drop all the columns from the object browser and then delete the ones you don't want. At least that way you don;t have any typos.

I would be concerned about the design of a table with that many columns. Espceially if they really are N1-N99. You may need a redesign to a related table. Also wide tables can cause performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Using dynamic sql is the closest you can get to not writing the columns. Here is an example:

```
declare @sql varchar(max)

select @sql = coalesce(@sql+',', 'select ') + 'n' + cast(number as varchar(2))
from master..spt_values as N 
where type = 'P' and 
number between 2 and 29 

set @sql = @sql + ' from <yourtable>'

--select @sql
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: voting this down is a bit harsh as the result of this is: select n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7,n8,n9,n10,n11,n12,n13,n14,n15,n16,n17,n18,n19,n20,n21,n22,n23,n24,n25,n26,n27,n28,n29 from <yourtable>

Comment: Dynamic SQL is the only solution to the question.  I'd argue that "not possible" would be an incorrect answer.  "Not preferable" would be correct.