# SQL query to select a range

Tags: c#, excel

I need to write an sql query (in c#) to select excel sheet data in **only the "C" column** starting from C19. But i cant specify the ending cell number because more data are getting added to the column. Hence i need to know how to specify the end of the column. Please help. I have mentioned the query that i'm using. And I have attached an image of the excel sheet that i'm using!.And I have attached the output datagridview!

```
//Generte Oracle Datatable
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
            + @"Data Source=" + textBox1.Text + ";" + @"Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=Yes""");
            conn.Open();

            OleDbCommand ccmd = new OleDbCommand(@"Select * From [SPAT$]", conn);
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(ccmd);                     
            DataTable Oracle = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(Oracle);

            for (int y = 19; y < Oracle.Rows.Count; y++)
            {
                var value = Oracle.Rows[y][3].ToString();           
            }   
            dataGridView1.DataSource = Oracle.AsEnumerable().Where((row, index) => index > 3).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368505/is-it-possible-to-select-sql-server-data-using-column-ordinal-position

Comment: i don't think it is related..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Approach, using OLE Query:

```
OleDbCommand ccmd = new OleDbCommand(@"Select * From [SPAT$]", conn);
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(ccmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

for (int i = 19; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var value = dt.Rows[i][3].ToString(); // here 3 refers to column 'C'
}
```

**For criteria based DataTable**

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.AsEnumerable()
                          .Where((row, index) => index >= 19)
                          .CopyToDataTable();
```

**For Column "C" only**

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.AsEnumerable()
                      .Where((row, index) => index >= 19)
                      .Select(t => t[3].ToString()).ToList();
```

Second Approach, using Excel COM object:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("path to book");
Excel.Worksheet xlSheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1]; // get first sheet
Excel.Range xlRange = xlSheet.UsedRange; // get the entire used range

int numberOfRows = xlRange.Rows.Count;

List<string> columnValue = new List<string>();
// loop over each column number and add results to the list

int c = 3; // Column 'C'
for(int r = 19; r <= numberOfRows; r++)
{
    if(xlRange.Cells[r,c].Value2 != null) // ADDED IN EDIT
    {
        columnValue.Add(xlRange.Cells[r,c].Value2.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I have attached the excel sheet and inserted the query. Please help

Comment: Have you applied this condition, Where((row, index) => index >= 19) as written in the answer?

Comment: i corrected it and executed the program. Now it displays all the columns from 23rd row. I have attached the new output. But i need rows from 20th column(line no. 1). i wanted 19th column as the header, but it could be ignored. Anyway i corrected i=16 and now i can obtain the columns from 19th row. Can you please help me in obtaining only the column "C" data

Comment: i changed the sql statement as "@"Select F2 From [SPAT$]", conn" and i could obtain the required result. Thanks alot for you help on this issue. I really appreciate your help since yersterday