# DataGridView get column title only

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` which is filled with the data that is in the table in my MySQL database.
But I don't want to get all the lines.

I have for example:  Name Surname E_Mail text

I want to get the title Name Surname and so on

But what I don't want is that I also get for example: Max Musterman | email@at.at | blablabal

I only want to get the Title and it should work for all tables for example if I switch the table which has only 2 columns : Computer | Cost

I want to get in my `DataGridView` Computer and Cost but again not the data for example HP 700€

I hope its clear what I want. But for now I get the Table title with the data and I don't want to get the data :(. Here is the code that gets me the whole table:

```
private void BindGrid()
{
    IPHostEntry Host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    string IPAddress = Host.AddressList[1].ToString();
    // MessageBox.Show(IPAddress);
    string datasource = IPAddress;
    string database = "datenbank";
    string port = "xxx";
    string UID = "xxx";
    string pw = "xx";

    string myConnection;
    myConnection = string.Format("datasource=" + datasource + ";" + "Database=" + database + ";" + "port=" + port + ";" + "UID=" + UID + ";" + "password=" + pw);

    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(myConnection))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Formular", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: all lines? all columns? data? title? Shown in the grid? Please make your question shorter and clearer

Comment: Sorry my English is not that good. What i want is that i get the coloumn names only and that should be then displayed in Datagridview. I want ID NAME if the table contains only those  2 coloumn names. But i dont want the data for example:  1 | Thomas

Comment: SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'your_table'

i found this somewhere and tested it on mysql and it worked but how do i change the code above to make it work?

Comment: here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/368578/891715

Comment: i replaced it with: SELECT * FROM Formular now i get what i want but can i change it i want it like this: ID Name Surname and not down down down