# peewee orm: bulk insert using a subquery but is based on python-side-data

Tags: python, sql, orm, bulkinsert, peewee

peewee allows bulk inserts via [`insert_many()`](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Model.insert_many) and [`insert_from()`](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Model.insert_from), however `insert_many()` allows a list of data to be inserted, but does not allow data computed from other parts of the database. `insert_from()` *does* allow data computed from other parts of the database, but does not allow any data to be sent from python.

### Example:

Assuming a model structure like so:

```
class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class Person(BaseModel):
    name = CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class StatusUpdate(BaseModel):
    person = ForeignKeyField(Person, related_name='statuses')
    status = TextField()
    timestamp = DateTimeField(constraints=[SQL('DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')], index=True)
```

And some initial data:

```
Person.insert_many(rows=[{'name': 'Frank'}, {'name': 'Joe'}, {'name': 'Arnold'}]).execute()
print ('Person.select().count():',Person.select().count())
```

Output:

```
Person.select().count(): 3
```

Say we want to add a bunch new status updates, like the ones in this list:

```
new_status_updates = [ ('Frank', 'wat')
                     , ('Frank', 'nooo')
                     , ('Joe', 'noooo')
                     , ('Arnold', 'nooooo')]
```

We might try to use `insert_many()` like so:

```
StatusUpdate.insert_many( rows=[{'person': 'Frank', 'status': 'wat'}
                              , {'person': 'Frank', 'status': 'nooo'}
                              , {'person': 'Joe', 'status': 'noooo'}
                              , {'person': 'Arnold', 'status': 'nooooo'}]).execute()
```

But this would fail: the `person` field expects a `Person` model or a `Person.id`, and we would have to make an extra query to retrieve those from the names.

We might be able to avoid this with `insert_from()` allows us to make subqueries, but `insert_from()` has no way of processing our lists or dictionaries. What to do?

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to use the SQL `VALUES` clause as part of a `SELECT` statement.

If you are familiar with SQL, you may have seen the `VALUES` clause before, it is commonly used as part of an `INSERT` statement like so:

```
INSERT INTO statusupdate (person_id,status)
VALUES (1, 'my status'), (1, 'another status'), (2, 'his status');
```

This tells the database to insert three rows - AKA tuples - into the table `statusupdate`.

Another way of inserting things though is to do something like:

```
INSERT INTO statusupdate (person_id,status)
SELECT ..., ... FROM <elsewhere or subquery>;
```

This is equivalent to the `insert_from()` functionality that peewee provides.

But there is another less common thing you can do: you can use the `VALUES` clause in *any* select to provide literal values. Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES (1,2,3), (4,5,6)) as my_literal_values;
```

This will return a result-set of two rows/tuples, each with 3 values.

So, if you can convert the "bulk" insert into a `SELECT/FROM/VALUES` statement, you can then do whatever transformations you need to do (namely, convert Person.name values to corresponding Person.id values) and then combine it with the peewee 'insert_from()` functionality.

So let us see how this would look.

First let us begin constructing the `VALUES` clause itself. We want properly escaped values, so we will use question marks instead of the values for now, and put the actual values in later.

```
#this is gonna look like '(?,?), (?,?), (?,?)'
# or '(%s,%s), (%s,%s), (%s,%s)' depending on the database type
values_question_marks = ','.join(['(%s, %s)' % (db.interpolation,db.interpolation)]*len(new_status_updates))
```

The next step is to construct the values clause. Here is our first attempt:

```
--the %s here will be replaced by the question marks of the clause
--in postgres, you must have a name for every item in `FROM`
SELECT * FROM (VALUES %s) someanonymousname
```

OK, so now we have a result-set that looks like:

```
name | status
-----|-------
...  | ...
```

Except! There are no column names. This will cause us a bit of heartache in a minute, so we have to figure out a way to give the result-set proper column names.

The postgres way would be to just alter the `AS` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES %s) someanonymousname(name,status)
```

sqlite3 does not support that (grr).

So we are reduced to a kludge. Luckily stackoverflow provides: [Is it possible to select sql server data using column ordinal position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32009395/586784), and we can construct something like this:

```
SELECT NULL as name, NULL as status WHERE 1=0
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (VALUES %s) someanonymousname
```

This works by first creating an empty result-set with the proper column-names, and then concatenating the result-set from the `VALUES` clause to it. This will produce a result-set that has the proper column-names, will work in sqlite3, and in postgres.

Now to bring this back to peewee:

```
values_query = """
(
    --a trick to make an empty query result with two named columns, to more portably name the resulting
    --VALUES clause columns (grr sqlite)
    SELECT NULL as name, NULL as status WHERE 1=0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES %s) someanonymousname
)
"""

values_query %= (values_question_marks,)

#unroll the parameters into one large list
#this is gonna look like ['Frank', 'wat', 'Frank', 'nooo', 'Joe', 'noooo' ...]
values_query_params = [value for values in new_status_updates for value in values]

#turn it into peewee SQL
values_query = SQL(values_query,*values_query_params)
data_query = (Person
                .select(Person.id, SQL('values_list.status').alias('status'))
                .from_(Person,values_query.alias('values_list'))
                .where(SQL('values_list.name') == Person.name))


insert_query = StatusUpdate.insert_from([StatusUpdate.person, StatusUpdate.status], data_query)

print (insert_query)
insert_query.execute()
print ('StatusUpdate.select().count():',StatusUpdate.select().count())
```

Output:

```
StatusUpdate.select().count(): 4
```